# Is it possible to fill in forms with pdfLaTeX or similar?

Tags: pdf, forms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Quickly add text to existing pdf files / fill forms](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6188/quickly-add-text-to-existing-pdf-files-fill-forms)

I think I have heard of some possibility to fill in the values of PDF forms using the (La)TeX programs. I mean not how to typeset a PDF form but how to fill the values of a given one.

Is this possible or am I remembering something completely wrong?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6188/quickly-add-text-to-existing-pdf-files-fill-forms.

Comment: And by given one you mean an existing PDF form, created perhaps in some other publishing software?

Comment: `@ChristianWolf` please provide an example form. (I totally want to write an over-engineered answer which would be "turn the pdf into a bitmap, find all blank rectangular regions using some crazy algorithm, then use the `pdfpages` package to insert the original pdf, superimposing a label for each rectangle detected. Then in a second run let the user insert text for each label.)

Comment: @ChristianWolf I closed this question as a duplicate, kindly have a look at the possible duplicate link, I hope this helps. If your question is different though, you could edit it to make it clear, also please edit to include answers to the Bruno's and Werner's comments then.